# R Shiny - How to output text from a loop inside a reactive function that itself returns a graph

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny version of a program.

Currently, when an `actionButton` is pressed the program does some processing inside a loop, then outputs a graph. That works fine.

What I'd like to do is have the processing loop create a block of HTML output that will change each iteration. Once complete the graph should be displayed.

I've created simple skeleton code below to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. It fails to display any text, producing an error message saying:

> Error in func() : object 'h' not found

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

```
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(  actionButton("go", "Go!") ),

    fluidRow(htmlOutput("html")),

    fluidRow(plotOutput('plot'))
 ),

server = function(input, output) {

  myPlot <- eventReactive(input$go, {

    for (i in 1:5){
      h <- HTML("some text to be displayed")

      cat(i) # outputs to the console, just for debugging

      Sys.sleep(1) # pause for 1 second
    }

    hist(runif(15))
  })

  output$html <- renderUI({ h }) # This doesn't produce any output

  output$plot <- renderPlot({ myPlot() }) # This displays a graph after the loop terminates
})


runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to output a variable that's changed within a reactive context. Those changes go out of scope. What you want is an observer, combined with isolate to achieve the same thing as `eventReactive` but with persisting variables.

try this

```
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(  actionButton("go", "Go!") ),

    fluidRow(htmlOutput("html")),

    fluidRow(plotOutput('plot'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    theText <- reactiveValues(htmlVar = NULL)
    observe({
      input$go
      isolate({
        for (i in 1:5){
          theText$htmlVar <- HTML("some text to be displayed")

          cat(i) # outputs to the console, just for debugging

          Sys.sleep(.1) # pause for 100ms 
        }
      })
    })
    myPlot <- reactive({input$go
                        print("setting myPlot")
                        return (hist(runif(15)))
      })

    output$html <- renderUI({ theText$htmlVar }) 

    output$plot <- renderPlot({ return (myPlot()) }) # This displays a graph after the loop terminates
  })

runApp(app)
```

if you're changing the HTML output consistently in your actual program, you can replace the `input$go` in the `myPlot` reactive with `theText$htmlVar`, then order of the functions wouldn't matter, since the text change would trigger the graphing. Depends what you're actually going for.